# Low-variance time set or Low-varying time set

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, grammar, british-english, mathematics

I have a time set like: {5 seconds, 5.1 seconds, 4.9 seconds ....} -> the time values do not change much (has low variance).

Can I define it as: Low-variance time set or Low-varying time set?

I mean, is it grammatically correct? If not how to say it in one word?

Another question: can I say it as Low-value time set (I want to say that it contains small time numbers).

Please help (not good in english). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the proposed "Low-varying" term would feel unnatural for a native speaker.

"Low" is generally only used with noun forms, e.g. "low variance" or "low probability".  With a word like "varying", you would usually attach an adverb, e.g. "minimally-varying", "slightly-varying", or "mildly-varying", just to name a few.

We might also choose to say something a little more verbose, e.g. "a set of times with low variance".

"Low-value time set" is somewhat more natural, though I think again a native speaker would choose something more verbose, e.g. "a set of low-value times" or "a set of times with low values".

Being concise is a good goal, as it is considerate of your reader's time, but it can cost them time when there's no brief-but-easily-understood term available.  Sometimes it's better to expand a little.